# Drupal node_save is not saving fields

Tags: drupal-7

I have just stumbled upon very strange behaviour. In my code I am saving new node with some fields. I must say this used to work perfectly well. However now it just stopped working. I use the devel module to print out the content of objects and variables and this is my code:

```
dsm($node);
node_save($node);
dsm($node);
```

The first dsm() function displays node object as I created it and as it is supposed to be. The second dsm() function displays entirely correct node object with nid populated, fields content, etc... However, none of the fields is saved in database although there is new record in {node} table. Also, node_save does not generate any kind of error.

Any idea what is happening here?

This is the function storing the node:

```
function manhattan_incident_save($data) {
if ($data['nid']) {
  $node = node_load($data['nid']);
  manhattan_compare_changes($node, $data);
}
else {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'incident';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title = manhattan_create_incident_id();
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;      
}

$node->field_incident_popis[$node->language][0]['value'] = $data['field_incident_popis'];
$node->field_incident_popis[$node->language][0]['safe_value'] = check_plain($data['field_incident_popis']);

$node->field_incident_agent[$node->language][0]['uid'] = isset($data['field_incident_agent'])?intval($data['field_incident_agent']):NULL;

$node->field_incident_zdroj[$node->language][0]['tid'] = intval($data['field_incident_zdroj']);
$node->og_group_ref[$node->language][0]['target_id'] = $data['field_incident_oblast']?intval($data['field_incident_oblast']):variable_get('manhattan_public_form_default_area_nid', NULL);
$node->field_incident_riesitel[$node->language][0]['uid'] = isset($data['field_incident_riesitel'])?intval($data['field_incident_riesitel']):NULL;
$node->field_incident_typ[$node->language][0]['tid'] = intval($data['field_incident_typ']);
$node->field_incident_doplnenie[$node->language][0]['nid'] = intval($data['field_incident_doplnenie']);
$node->field_incident_sposob_kontaktu[$node->language][0]['value'] = $data['field_incident_sposob_kontaktu'];
$node->field_incident_dovod_vzniku[$node->language][0]['tid'] = intval($data['field_incident_dovod_vzniku']);

if ($data['field_incident_suvisiaci_zaznam']) {
  foreach ($data['field_incident_suvisiaci_zaznam'] as $file) {
    $result = manhattan_save_files($file);
    if ($result) {
      $node->field_incident_suvisiaci_zaznam[$node->language][] = array('nid' => $result); 
    }
  }
}

// now create/save the customer
if (function_exists('customer_customer_save')) {
  $customer = $data;
  $customer['nid'] = $data['field_incident_customer'];
  $result = customer_customer_save($customer); 
  if ($result) {
    watchdog('upvs', $result['message'], array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  }
  else {
    watchdog('upvs', t('There was a problem with saving customer %nid'), array('%nid' => $data['nid']), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  }
}
// now we store nid of saved customer to the node object
$node->field_incident_customer[$node->language][0]['nid'] = $result['nid'];

dsm($node);
node_save($node); 
dsm($node);

if ($data['nid']) {
  watchdog('upvs', t('Incident number %title has been succesfully saved.'), array('%title' => $node->title), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
}
else {
  watchdog('upvs', t('Incident number %title has been succesfully created.'), array('%title' => $node->title), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
}

return $node;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are preparing the node object correctly? Can you provide more details like how are you adding values to the object ?

Comment: 100 per cent sure. It used to work a day or two ago... Nevertheless, I have edit the original text so in now contains the code as well, you can have a look. And again, after "saving" I am getting correctly populated node object and correct record in {node} table. The fields are not stored at all.

Comment: So, if i understood correctly, node_save is not working now even though with no code change since then. That is strange. Can you check logs ?

Comment: There were some other changes somewhere else, of course, but the point is that node_save returns perfectly valid node object, no error, nothing in logs whatsoever but it just does not save the fields data in the database. Yes, it's strange.

Comment: Can you please check the table health where these fields data is getting stored ?

Comment: Tables are ok. I am using this code on another server and it is the same problem. Also, when editing existing node, fields gets updated correctly.

Comment: Did you manage to find the problem for this issue? I'm having a similar one.

Comment: I am so sorry, I really can't remember. Could you create a new issue a post a link here, I can have a look and maybe I could help.